# Remove empty entries during string split

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I use this helper function to remove the empty entries.

Is there a built-in way for this?

```
def getNonEmptyList(str, splitSym):
    lst=str.split(splitSym)

    lst1=[]
    for entry in lst:
        if entry.strip() !='':
            lst1.append(entry)

    return lst1
```

Comment: If your data didn't have extra whitespace, you wouldn't have to do this

Comment: You can use: lst1 = [x for x in str.split(splitSym) if x]

Answer (score 9):

[str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

For example:

```
>>> '1 2 3'.split()
['1', '2', '3']
>>> '1 2 3'.split(maxsplit=1)
['1', '2 3']
>>> '   1   2   3   '.split()
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 3):

This split could be done more compactly with a comprehension like:

```
def getNonEmptyList(str, splitSym):
    return [s for s in str.split(splitSym) if s.strip() != '']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use filter

```
def get_non_empty_list(s, delimiter):
    return list(filter(str.strip, s.split(delimiter)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split text by newline and remove any empty lines here's one liner :)

```
lines = [l for l in text.split('\n') if l.strip()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to capture the extra whitespace.

```
import re 
split_re = r'\s*{}\s*'.format(splitSym)
return re.split(split_re, string)
```